# jQuery how to create loops to avoid repetition

Tags: jquery

I have a text file with values, which I read and display on my page. I'm trying to figure out whether there is a way to create a jQuery loops to process this information, so there isn't that many repetitions:

```
   $('#number1').text(table[0][2]);
   $('#number2').text(table[1][2]);
   $('#number3').text(table[2][2]);
   $('#number4').text(table[3][2]);
   $('#number5').text(table[4][2]);
   $('#number6').text(table[5][2]);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are many ways to do it, but loops/iterations are basics in any language, for JS see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the loop/iteration basics and the logic in your code, i think the easiest way to do it is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  $('#number' + (i+1)).text(table[i][2]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the element order in page is same as order of array you can use [`text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which loops over all the elements in collection and exposes their index within the collection.

```
$('#number1,#number2,#number3....').text(function(i){
  return table[i][2];
});
```

If all these elements had a common class it would simplify the initial selector

Comment: Brilliant! Just a good thing to note though, is that this will only work if the DOM elements are in the correct order :) if `#number6` somehow explicitly ends up being the first being parsed/selected by JS, that will throw the pattern off, for example. However I doubt this is going to be the case.

Comment: @Terry right, I made that basic assumption also without explicitly stating it.

Comment: @charlietfl Very interesting, thank you! Can it work if it's not only the [2] but this parameter also increments?

Comment: @RulliSmith probably but not clear what you need without a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each( table, function ( index ) {
    $( "#number"  + ( index + 1 ) ).text( table[ index ][ 2 ] );
});
```

Comment: What if also the second parameter increments, it's not always [2]?
@sgiant

Comment: How so? Give me an example @Rulli Smith